# When using Salesforce as an Identity Provider, does it authenticate against it's user base?

Tags: single-sign-on, identity, pricing

If I have purchased Salesforce for 10 users, does that means that I can only perform authentication against those 10 users only ?

To put it another way, if I have a website that has 1,000 registered users, does that mean that I need to have 1,000 of those users mapped to 1,000 user accounts within Salesforce so that I can use Salesforce as an IDP ?

And does that imply that I need to purchase 1,000 user accounts from Salesforce ?

Comment: You should look at Salesforce Communities

Comment: You should contact your sales rep, but in short - you should be purchasing `Identity` or `External Identity` licenses for these 1,000 users whose identity will be managed and authenticated by Salesforce. What's the use case you're trying to solve for here?

Comment: To @cropredy - Is Salesforce Communities a product from Salesforce ?

Comment: To @MarkPond - Ok. The use-case is this: - I have a Salesforce site and a Wordpress site. I want users of a Wordpress site to be authenticated by Salesforce acting as an IDP.  Does that mean that I have to purchase a 1,000 user license to perform SSO between Salesforce and a Wordpress-based site for 1,000 users ?

Comment: [SFDC Communities](http://www.salesforce.com/communities/pricing/)

Comment: @ChristopherLean Yes, you need 1000 licenses to authenticate 1000 users. You should contact your Salesforce sales rep as the pricing for this could be flexible - however nobody here can ultimately determine that for you.